# Object and string do not work in the same way when using transclude property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've read some articles on how different scopes are used when using directive's transclude property. While debugging my code I've created following code snippet. The weird thing is that `_object` and `_string` variables behave differently. `_object` is being updated in the parent scope, while `_string` is not. Here's a demo http://jsbin.com/ruvixilukaci/1/edit

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>Object: {{ _object }}</div>
  <div>String: {{ _string }}</div>

  <directive-example>
    <p><input type="text" ng-model="_object._string"></p>
    <p><input type="text" ng-model="_string" /></p>
  </directive-example>
</body>
```

Controller/Directive source code:

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope._object = {
    _string: 'Object string'
  };
  $scope._string = 'Default string';
})

.directive('directiveExample', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    transclude:true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'
  };
});
```

Do you have any clue of what is going on? I've tried various versions of Angular.JS also. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read here: [Understanding scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

> Scope inheritance is normally straightforward, and you often don't even need to know it is happening... until you try 2-way data binding (i.e., form elements, ng-model) to a primitive (e.g., number, string, boolean) defined on the parent scope from inside the child scope. It doesn't work the way most people expect it should work. What happens is that the child scope gets its own property that hides/shadows the parent property of the same name.

Basically your child scope is getting its own copy of the `_string` property and it's hiding the parent scope's.

Comment: Oh I see, so the child scope behaves differently when it comes to primitives and it doesn't have to do anything with `transclude`. This is the first time I've experienced this. Thank you very much for your feedback.